# Как сделать равными отступы для ТЕКСТА кнопок

Tags: android

Как сделать равными отступы от краёв экрана до ТЕКСТА кнопок? 
Т.е. от правого края экрана до начала текста правой кнопки, и от левого края экрана - до конца текста левой кнопки? Когда текст в кнопках одной длины, всё выглядит хорошо:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда тексты в кнопках разной длины, расстояние от краёв экрана до текста становится разным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит мой layout с кнопками:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="@string/skip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Можно было бы сделать равными отступы от краёв экрана до кнопок, но, несмотря на то, что `layout_width` задана как `"wrap_content"`, вокруг текста есть ещё какой-то "padding". Я пробовала добавить для кнопок `android:padding="0dp"`, но это ничего не изменило. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Пробовали прописать для кнопок `android:gravity="left" / "right"?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, да но почему-то  gravity тут работает вообще странно: http://joxi.ru/nAyBqv9IYxQW6r

Comment: А если у вас бэк кнопок `null` может проще сделать `TextView`? Или TV с бэком)

Comment: @Jarvis_J, да, наверное, и такой вариант мог бы помочь. Но я нашла ещё один способ, как это сделать, кажется, проще - с `android:minWidth="0dp"`.

Comment: Интересное решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, я нашла решение - добавить `android:minWidth="0dp"`. Это свойство убирает "padding" вокруг текста в кнопке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И также я добавила отступы от кнопок:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        ...
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        ...
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что вам нужены:

```
    android:paddingStart="40dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
```

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместе с `android:background="@null"` эти свойства, к сожалению, не работают(